# Redirect to partial view on another controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new in asp.net mvc programming, please be gentle... :)

Please notice that the following views are all PARTIAL views! Methods are called through Ajax and redirect to partial views with lists, forms are posted through Ajax, etc. OK, here we go...

1st controller named AlertsController. One of the methods is ResolveAlert(Guid id) which returns RedirectToAction -> UnresolvedAlerts() which is just a list of unresolved alerts.

2nd contoller named FrontDeskController. One of the methods is CustomerDetails(Guid id) which lists the customer and alerts that he might have.

I want to be able to "Resolve an alert" (thus use the method of the 1st controller) but return to the page that I was before instead of going to the redirected page that the method returns.

I added a second parameter to the ResolveAlert() method which lists a returnUrl string. I manage to send the Url that I want it to redirect to but I get just the partial (not rendered inside the whole page as it should)...

Here's my ResolveAlert method on my AlertsController:

```
// Resolve Alert POST
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Resolve(AlertModel model, string redirectUrl)
    {
        await _AlertsService.ResolveAsync(model);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(redirectUrl))
            return Redirect(redirectUrl);
        return RedirectToAction("Unresolved");
    }
```

...and here is my CustomerDetails() method on my FrontDeskController:

```
// Display Customer Alerts
        public async Task<PartialViewResult> CustomerDetails(AttendanceModel model, Guid id)
        {
            var customer = await _CustomersService.ReadAsync(id);
            ViewData["Customer"] = await _CustomersService.ReadCustomerExtendedAsync(id);

            var alerts = await _AlertsService.ReadCustomerAlertsAsync(id);
            ViewData["Alerts"] = alerts.Where(x => x.IsResolved == false).ToList();

            return PartialView("_CustomerDetails", model);
        }
```

The ResolveAlert() method of the first controller is called in two steps... 1st I call a modal from the CustomerDetails view:

```
function resolveAlert(alertId, customerId) {

        var returnTo = '/FrontDesk/CustomerDetails/' + customerId;

        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Alerts/Resolve/' + alertId,
            data: {returnUrl : returnTo},
            dataType: 'html'
        }).then(function (html) {
            $('#dialog-container').html(html);
            showDialog();
        });
    }
```

...then on the modal I have:

```
@{
    var data = Request.Params["returnUrl"];
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Resolve", "Alerts", new { redirectUrl = data}, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "partial", OnSuccess = "hideDialog" }, new { id = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{ ..... textbox with some notes that I can post while resolving the alert ..... }
```

... and (finally) here is the final part at the bottom of my modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#form').validate({
        rules: {
            AlertNotes: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {

            $.ajax({
                url: $(form).attr("action"),
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                type: $(form).attr("method")
            }).then(function (result) {
                $("#partial").html(result);
                hideDialog();
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I think that in order for the returned partial to get rendered correctly inside its container I should be returning a RedirectToAction from the ResolveAlert() method but the problem is that it belongs on a different controller...

Is it possible to get this working somehow or should I just bite the bullet and forget about having those pages as partials, get rid of the Ajax calls and use normal Url.Action() links?

Answer (score 0):

It was just a Javascript/Ajax bug in my code.... Please disregard the question...

For those wondering, I had 2 forms using the same id. JS died silently allowing the form to be posted normally and not through Ajax. It had me scratching my head for a while now. Too bad that web development tools and VS in particular can't snipe such errors and provide a meaningful hint to assist you in debugging...